# I have a problem with my desktop

Tags: 14.04, login, display

There's something wrong with my desktop.
Yesterday, I was using my laptop (Toshiba Satellite L655) as usual. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed, and everything was ok. I never had any problem before. But today, when I woke up and turned on my laptop and logged in to my account, it displayed nothing except for the background. No menu, files, nothing. It just shows the background.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you get a command prompt? eg. **`Ctrl-Alt-T`** or **`Ctrl-Alt-F1`**

Comment: That question does not yet have a **14.04** specific answer.

Comment: I can open the Ctrl-Alt-T, but I can't open the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1).

Comment: Try **EdGunter**'s response (specific to **14.04**) in http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score -1):

If you able to get the terminal to work maybe you can try and run `sudo apt-get update`

Check out this [thread](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?301083-Ubuntu-14-04-No-Gui-after-Login) you might find your answers there.

Comment: I can open the Ctrl-Alt-F1.
Does that work?

Comment: Read the thread that I posted. There are some relative posts on this topic